# In WSO2 APIM Publisher getting error html response with 200 OK status

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am getting error html response when using wso2 publisher hostname to get an Api value but with original endpoint it returning correct response.
[https://wso2apim-publisher-route-wso2-deploy.apps.cloud.admcoecloud.local:443/customer/2/api/customers/test/hello![This](https://wso2apim-publisher-route-wso2-deploy.apps.cloud.admcoecloud.local:443/customer/2/api/customers/test/hello!%5BThis) is when tried from WSO2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz21J.jpg)

http://customerinfo-javapipeline-dev-apps.apps.cloud.admcoecloud.local/api/customers/test/hello
I am getting correct response.
[image: This is when tried from backend API]

I imported the swagger file in API publisher and I was expecting to get correct response.

I checked in Postman response for this API with WSo2 302 response is coming.
[Postman console response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7IU1.jpg)

Comment: Did you deploy and publish the API correctly? Can you call the API from devportal successfully after subscribing to an app?

Comment: Yes I have deployed it correctly and No getting html response although 200 ok is status code but not able to get correct response

Comment: Can you post the curl you get from the devportal tryout?

Comment: Your requests are going to the 9443 port. Check the routing rules. The API request traffic should route to the 8243 port

Comment: @Pubci in Openshift if I change port in deployment Yaml of publisher to 8243 it is not working. Still url is coming as https://wso2apim-publisher-route-wso2-deploy.apps.cloud.admcoecloud.local:443/pizzashack/1.0.0/menu this.

Comment: I am doing this for the first time in Openshift, so need assistance

Comment: We gave the gateway route as the hostname under the gateway section in deployment.toml http_endpoint = "http://wso2apim-gw-route-wso2-deploy.apps.cloud.admcoecloud.local:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://wso2apim-gw-route-wso2-deploy.apps.cloud.admcoecloud.local:${https.nio.port}"      but receiving 404 error.

Comment: I still cannot consume the api .. I'm getting a response with http code 404 : {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /pizzashack/1.0.0/menu, HEALTH CHECK URL = /pizzashack/1.0.0/menu